# How to go about learning a heritage language that I lost as a child?

Tags: learning-methods, french

I used to be bilingual in French and English when I was very young but when I began school in Australia, I stopped speaking French so I could get better at English and now at 16 I can understand the general gist of a conversation but can barely speak any French. I'm wondering if it is any different to learning a second language or if the method I should go about is the same as a complete new learner. I have a French mum to practice with so that is helpful but I am confused on how I should go about learning considering my previous exposure to the language and due to the lack of information on this topic. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I would turn to the Alliance Française. There are several of them in Australia and they also do online stuff. No, it will not be like learning a second language since you had already at some point absorbed it. Now, you need to reawaken if and add to it.

Comment: I agree very much with @Lambie. You are at an advantage compared to people who learn French as a second language. Reviving dormant brains cells is easier than starting from scratch. You once spoke it & you have a mother at home who is a native speaker. Start by getting back into French immersively & only speak French at home. Avoid speaking English a home. Additionally, turn to Alliance Française. The one thing about all migrants is they take with them the language as it was spoken when they left. Over time, the language in the countries they migrated from evolves  but they speak the language

Comment: ... as it was spoken some time previously. Alliance Française will be able to help to you with how French has evolved since you migrated to Australia.